# Getting a "No default module defined for this application" exception while running controller unit tests in zend framework

Tags: exception, zend-framework, phpunit

I have an application with the default directory structure, for an application without custom modules (see structure figure at the end).

I have written a ControllerTestCase.php file as instructed in many tutorials, and I've created the appropriate bootstrap file as well (once again, see figures at the end).

I've written some model tests which run just fine, but when I started writing the index controller test file, with only one test in it, with only one line in it ("$this->dispatch('/');"), I'm getting the following exception when running phpunit (but navigating with the browser to the same location - all is good and working):

```
1) IndexControllerTest::test_indexAction_noParams
Zend_Controller_Exception: No default module defined for this application
```

Why is this ? What have I done wrong ?

Appendixes:
**Directory structure:**

```
-proj/
  -application/
    -controllers/
      -IndexController.php
      -ErrorController.php
    -config/
    -layouts/
    -models/
    -views/
      -helpers/
      -scripts/
        -error/
          -error.phtml
        -index/
          -index.phtml
    -Bootstrap.php
  -library/
  -tests/
    -application/
      -controllers/
        -IndexControllerTest.php
      -models/
      -bootstrap.php
      -ControllerTestCase.php
    -library/
    -phpunit.xml
  -public/
    -index.php
```

(Basically I have some more files in the models directory, but that's not relevant to this question.)

**application.ini file:**

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "My"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.view[] = 
phpSettings.date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

**tests/application/bootstrap.php file:**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'testing'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'), // this project' library
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

require_once 'ControllerTestCase.php';
```

**ControllerTestCase.php file:**

```
<?php
require_once ('Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php');
class ControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase {
    /**
     * 
     * @var Zend_Application
     */
    protected $application;

    protected function setUp(){
        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function appBootstrap(){
        $this->application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV,
                                                  APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known bug.
Here is my workaround to fix this issue:

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
require_once 'Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php';

abstract class ControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    protected $_application;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function appBootstrap()
    {
        $this->_application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV,
              APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
        );
        $this->_application->bootstrap();

        /**
         * Fix for ZF-8193
         * http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8193
         * Zend_Controller_Action->getInvokeArg('bootstrap') doesn't work
         * under the unit testing environment.
         */
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        if($front->getParam('bootstrap') === null) {
            $front->setParam('bootstrap', $this->_application->getBootstrap());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm using zend framework 1.10.2, so this bug you're talking about is not there at all, however - you did lead me to the solution, and that is that I was missing the $this->_application->bootstrap() call in the appBootstrap method. Please edit your answer to remove the reference to the bug, as it is not the case.
Thanks

Comment: i am at 1.10.6 now but i seem to still experience that bug ... dunno if i did something wrong tho. if i remove that fix, it fails

Comment: @jiewmeng Take a look at setup described by Matthew: [Testing Zend Framework Applications](http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/testing-zend-framework-applications)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to include this line after `parent::setUp()`

```
$this->_application->getBootstrap()->getPluginResource('frontcontroller')->init();
```