# Unit Testing with Zend_Test: Call to a member function hasResource() on a non-object in Zend's ErrorController

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, doctrine-orm, zend-test

I am getting this error

> `Fatal error: Call to a member function hasResource() on a non-object in D:\Projects\Tickle\application\controllers\ErrorController.php on line 53`

where line 53 looks like

```
if (!$bootstrap->hasResource('Log')) {
```

It seems like `$this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')` returns `null`. I got no other errors. I read somewhere else for another problem that an exception maybe raised that resets my controller or bootstrap or something like that. Is it possible that that exception not be shown? even in the PHP error log?

My current setup looks like

- PHPUnit's bootstrap.php http://pastebin.com/YiP7i736
- I tried removing all files/test till I am left with 1 test http://pastebin.com/CsrLys4v

The single test runs fine but I still got the error

```
D:\Projects\Tickle\tests>phpunit
PHPUnit 3.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.
Fatal error: Call to a member function hasResource() on a non-object in D:\Projects\Tickle\application\controllers\Error
Controller.php on line 53
```

Comment: have you managed to run the tests?

Comment: @St.Woland, Hmm yes, now that you've asked, it seems all tests run, at least when I just have 1 test. Maybe it gets thrown right at the end, does it trigger anything?

Comment: Try disabling error resource for your application and see what output you get. It may be related to some other error in your code.

Comment: @St.Woland, what do you mean by disabling error resource?

Comment: There is a resource named ErrorHandler. It initializes controller plugin ErrorHandler. I suggest that you look up your application.ini for any mentioning of `errorHandler` and comment those lines out.

Comment: @St.Woland, It seems my `application.ini` generated by Zend_Tool does not have `errorHandler` in it. It looks like http://pastebin.com/DqbvZC5K

Answer (score 6, accepted):

bootstrap param is registered when you call `$application->run()`. In your unit test bootstrap, run is not called. You have to set the boostrap param yourself with this code :

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setParam('bootstrap', $bootstrap);
```

Comment: Oh ... I can use `$application->getBootstrap()` but how can I get `$application` from my `ControllerTestCase`? I tried putting that line in my phpunit's `bootstrap.php` it didn't work, I still got missing resource

Comment: Some oddities I find too, I am getting "No default module defined" tho I am not using modules and in my `application.ini` I have already defined `controllerDirectory` my Qn & Sol [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507165/zend-test-no-default-module-defined-for-this-application). I wonder if they are related. It seems like my frontController is reset or something. When I `$bootstrap = $this->getFrontController()->getParam('bootstrap')` and `print_r($bootstrap)` I get nothing

Comment: Ok I solved the problem with **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507996/getting-a-no-default-module-defined-for-this-application-exception-while-runnin/2510549#2510549**